# $N$-body phase space for Fermi golden rule

Tags: quantum-mechanics, phase-space, dirac-delta-distributions, fermis-golden-rule

I was following along Mark Thomson's Modern Particle Physics, and stumble upe the derivation of d$n$ of Fermi golden rule on page 62:

> "...
> For the decay of a particle to a final state consisting of $N$ particles, there are $N-1$ independent momenta in the final state. Thus, the numer of independent states for an N-particle final state is
> \begin{equation}
> dn=\prod^{N-1}_{i=1} dn_i = \prod^{N-1}_{i=1} \frac{d^3\textbf{p}_i}{(2\pi)^3} \tag{A}.
> \end{equation}
> This can be expressend in a more democratic form including the momentum space volume for the $N$th particle $d^3\text{p}_N$ and using delta-function to impose momentum conservation
> \begin{equation}
> dn=\prod^{N-1}_{i=1} \frac{d^3\textbf{p}_i}{(2\pi)^3} \delta^3\left(\textbf{p}_a-\sum^N_{i=1}\textbf{p}_i\right)d^3\textbf{p}_N \tag{B},
> \end{equation}
> where $\textbf{p}_a$ is the momentum of the decaying particle.... (and so on) "

Based on the explanation between the steps, I don't understand why the three-dimensional dirac-delta function appear out of nowhere. I do know that physical significances imposing momentum conservation, but why does it have to take the form of dirac-delta? is there an intermediate steps that I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After giving some thoughts and times, I finally came to an answer to my own question. I hope this might help other who get the same problem. This come to some sloppy writing and definition of dirac-delta:

\begin{equation}
\int d^nx \delta^n(x-a) = 1\\
\end{equation}
similiarly,
\begin{equation}
\int d^3\textbf{p}_N \;\delta^3\left(\textbf{p}_a-\sum^N_{i=1} \textbf{p}_i\right) = 1
\end{equation}
Therefore, from (A)
\begin{align}
dn&=\prod^{N-1}_{i=1} dn_i, \\
&= \prod^{N-1}_{i=1} \frac{d^3\textbf{p}_i}{(2\pi)^3}, \\
&= \prod^{N-1}_{i=1} \frac{d^3\textbf{p}_i}{(2\pi)^3} \int \delta^3\left(\textbf{p}_a-\sum^N_{i=1}\textbf{p}_i\right)d^3\textbf{p}_N.
\end{align}
can be obtained (B) with slight correction to the book.